# how to enable syntax highlighting for c code in a textview on android studio?

Tags: android, c, syntax, highlighting

I created an application for students to learn software with examples. I have published it in play store. I'm continuing developemnt on this application. I want show syntax highlighting in all c codes but I haven't found a way to do it . I tried a lot of way to add syntax highlighting but It is not possible.

Comment: Please explain more about the ways you tried. Which one got you closest to your goal? What are the remaining problems?

Comment: A bit confused in here?. you need c language syntax highlighting for your android app or do you need to enable c language syntax highlighting for android studio. And you have also mentioned about a published play store app, could add a link of your app on the google play store, so we could figure out what you want.

Comment: The applications has "c" codes and another software language codes and I add the cods syntax highlighting. Codes become from sqlite database to a textview. I dont know that how can I syntax highlighting to codes. When I search, anyone say that you should write cods html form and then include your application and you should use html operations to android studio but I didnt cant this way.

Comment: [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cprogramlamaorneklerien.user.myapplication)

Comment: [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cprogramlamaorneklerien.user.myapplication)

Comment: @TevhitKarslı you can edit your original question and add the link rather  than adding answers, it is better if you could remove answer and edit the question with the links to play store

Answer (score 1):

If I got your requirements right, correct me if I'm wrong. You need to show syntax highlighting for code snippets (c language) on a text view, which your already exiting play store app only shows in black and white.

To get the highlighted html of the code snippet you could use [this site](https://tohtml.com/c/) and then you could get the html of the highlighted code snippet from the **HTML Code** section of the above linked site. After which you have two options to show it on the android application.

1. Using the **TextView**

   Using java you could populate the text view with the following util method

   ```
   myTextView.setTextsetText(Html.fromHtml("<pre style='color:#000000;background:#ffffff;'><span style='color:#004a43; '>#</span><span style='color:#004a43; '>include </span><span style='color:#800000; '>&lt;</span><span style='color:#40015a; '>stdio.h</span><span style='color:#800000; '>></span>\n" +
           "<span style='color:#800000; font-weight:bold; '>int</span> <span style='color:#400000; '>main</span><span style='color:#808030; '>(</span><span style='color:#808030; '>)</span>\n" +
           "<span style='color:#800080; '>{</span>\n" +
           "   <span style='color:#696969; '>// printf() displays the string inside quotation</span>\n" +
           "   <span style='color:#603000; '>printf</span><span style='color:#808030; '>(</span><span style='color:#800000; '>\"</span><span style='color:#0000e6; '>Hello, World!</span><span style='color:#800000; '>\"</span><span style='color:#808030; '>)</span><span style='color:#800080; '>;</span>\n" +
           "   <span style='color:#800000; font-weight:bold; '>return</span> <span style='color:#008c00; '>0</span><span style='color:#800080; '>;</span>\n" +
           "<span style='color:#800080; '>}</span>\n" +
           "</pre>"));
   ```
2. Using **WebViews**
   Once again using java you could populate a webView with the html code you obtained from the above mentioned site.

   ```
   WebView webView  = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
   webView.loadData("<pre style=\"color:#000000;background:#ffffff;\"><span style=\"color:#004a43; \">#</span><span style=\"color:#004a43; \">include </span><span style=\"color:#800000; \">&lt;</span><span style=\"color:#40015a; \">stdio.h</span><span style=\"color:#800000; \">&gt;</span>\n" +
           "<span style=\"color:#800000; font-weight:bold; \">int</span> <span style=\"color:#400000; \">main</span><span style=\"color:#808030; \">(</span><span style=\"color:#808030; \">)</span>\n" +
           "<span style=\"color:#800080; \">{</span>\n" +
           "   <span style=\"color:#696969; \">// printf() displays the string inside quotation</span>\n" +
           "   <span style=\"color:#603000; \">printf</span><span style=\"color:#808030; \">(</span><span style=\"color:#800000; \">\"</span><span style=\"color:#0000e6; \">Hello, World!</span><span style=\"color:#800000; \">\"</span><span style=\"color:#808030; \">)</span><span style=\"color:#800080; \">;</span>\n" +
           "   <span style=\"color:#800000; font-weight:bold; \">return</span> <span style=\"color:#008c00; \">0</span><span style=\"color:#800080; \">;</span>\n" +
           "<span style=\"color:#800080; \">}</span>\n" +
           "</pre>","text/html", "UTF-8");
   ```

Comment: So you need to dynamically syntax highlight it. if that is the case you need to write some kind of  parser which converts it on the go or you could use https://github.com/tiagohm/CodeView

Comment: Thanks for interest me. I did it :)))